# Highcharts error loading maps plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, highmaps

1. Load jQuery
2. Load Highcharts 4.0.1
3. Load Highmaps 1.1.6 (which says it is compatible with 4.0.x)

seeing this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: HighchartsAdapter.addAnimSetter is not a function
```

===

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.highcharts.com/4.0.1/highcharts.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.highcharts.com/maps/1.1.6/modules/map.js'></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/93ukkqoh/ (see error in the javascript console)

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: The fiddle is empty?

Comment: I'm loading the external libraries, see the error in the javascript console

Comment: Sorry, it looks like a mistake in the maps module description. Maps module v1.1.6 is compatible with Highcharts v4.1.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following libraries in the following order

```
 <script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js'></script>

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.highcharts.com/maps/1.1.6/modules/map.js'></script>
```